# Plot in Sweave PDF document is lagging my computer

Tags: r, pdf, plot, latex, sweave

I am trying to include a single, less than one-page-sized plot into a `Sweave`/`R` pdf document. This plot is based on huge amounts of data - i.e. in a small plot area there are tens of thousands of points. Whenever I include the plot normally through Sweave, I get huge lag when I open the resulting pdf. This is similar to the case of exporting an `eps` with tens of thousands of dots - even though the plot area is small it will lag heavily.

How do I code it such that a `png` is inserted, or equivalent, which doesn't keep all the information of every dot in the plot but just keeps the information of the pixels corresponding to the plot size?

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE,height=4>>=
plot(rnorm(100000))
@
\end{center}
\caption{Visualisation in Sweave which can lag computers}
\end{figure}
```

**I am looking for a LaTeX solution. This means no PNG**

Answer (score 1):

Use `png` like:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<label, fig=FALSE>>=
png('label.png')
plot(rnorm(100000))
dev.off()
@
\end{center}
\includegraphics{label}
\caption{Visualisation in Sweave which can lag computers}
\end{figure}
```

Or use the Sweave driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/thibautjombart/r-packages).

Comment: Does `label.png` get saved onto my local disk permanently (until I manually remove it)?

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `label' not found.

Comment: @user2763361: I have no errors, yes, it stored permanently (of course, until the recompile).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (not a direct answer to the question asked) is to replace a scatterplot with large numbers of points with a hexagonal binning plot instead.  The hexbin package (bioconductor) or the ggplot2 package both have functions for creating the hexagonal binning plots.  These plots will be smaller/faster than a scatterplot that contains many points, and for that many points the hexbin plot may even be more meaningful.